# Check if program was called manually or by system startup

Tags: c++

I have a C++ console program that runs at every system startup. I want to check if the program was called manually by the user and if so then do A, and if not then do B instead. The OS is Windows.

Comment: If name == main In python does something different than what you described. And your question is at least OS specific.

Comment: Edited question to clarify

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution is to pass an argument to your program at ”boot launch”.

This also makes it easy to test the behaviour without rebooting.

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: @YoelVinitsky simply add a command line argument to whatever shortcut/link/Registry command you use to run your program at startup. Then update your `main()` function to look for that argument. Working with command line arguments is a fundamental skill to know when writing console programs.